# How to add new Lookup into DefaultGazetteer programatically

Tags: java, gate

I want to add new Lookup into loaded `DefaultGazetteer` programatically.

If I add this string via file, it works perfectly

Any help will be much welcomed. Thanks

```
String test="hello@code=555.5@code_asociated_description=World@code1=@code2=@code3=@code4=@code5=@code6=@code7=";
gazetter.add(test, new Lookup("glossary.lst", "test", "test", "en"));
theList.add(new GazetteerNode(test, "@"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add a Lookup only:

```
    Lookup l = new Lookup("glossary.lst", "major", "minor", "en", "AnnotType");
    l.features = new HashMap<>();
    l.features.put("someFeatureName", "some value");
    gazetter.add("string to be found", l);
```

This will update the linear definition (`.def` & `.lst` files):

```
    LinearDefinition ld = gazetter.getLinearDefinition();

    //add .lst record
    LinearNode ln = new LinearNode("glossary.lst", "minor", "major", "en", "AnnotType");
    ld.add(ln);

    //add Lookup record
    Map<String, Object> features = new HashMap<>();
    features.put("someFeatureName", "some value");
    GazetteerNode gn = new GazetteerNode("string to be found", features);
    gn.setSeparator("@");
    GazetteerList theList = ld.getListsByNode().get(ln);
    theList.add(gn);

    //save updated files 
    theList.store();
    ld.store();

    //optionally re-init the gazetteer to make changes to work 
    gazetter.reInit();
```

If your gazetteer configuration is consistent (mainly the separator), then

```
theList.store(); ld.store(); gazetter.reInit();
```

will load the updated configuration. You do not necessarily have to combine the second approach with the first one. But because `store()` and `reInit()` are very expensive operations compared to Lookup addition, I do not recommend calling it frequently. I would prefer some kind of combination (as you mentioned in the comments) or **do the Lookup addition only** if you do not care about the `.def` & `.lst` files (you may be persisting your lookups already somehow/somewhere).

#### Removing Lookup(s)

Lookup **only**:

```
//This will remove all Lookups for given string
gazetteer.remove("string to be found");

//This will remove a specific Lookup only
//The method is not included in the Gazetteer interface
((DefaultGazetteer) gazetter).removeLookup("string to be found", l);
```

Linear definition **only**:

```
theList.remove(gn);
```

Comment: Thank you. You really helped me. *Lookup only* worked for me as I expected. The second one, adds into list, but does not load it (we need to combine both dynamic addition and lst update).

Comment: How can I remove added Lookup?

Comment: @Valijon - see my updated answer (added some comments about _need to combine both_ and Lookup remove).

Comment: Thank you. But, it still does not remove a Lookup. There is something strange: when I add a new Lookup via 1st method, it does not shown in `listsByNode` of gazetter instance (debug mode). Can it be the reason to not delete the Lookup?

Comment: @Valijon - see my answer to your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30623100/1857897
The **1st method will not modify the linear definition**.