# Gate : Reinitialising (ANNIE) Gazetteers at runtime

Tags: gate

Good Afternoon

I have an application that I am building that takes a users input and converts it in to a gazetteer.

I'd really like to be able to reinitialise a gazetteer when I run my app over a single documentas the gazetteer may have changed.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Many Thanks

Chris

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30569624/1857897 ... run time gazetteer changes as well as gazetteer re-init can be seen there.

Comment: Are you interested in **GATE Embedded** (java code) solution, or are you looking for some "script" (e.g. Groovy) for **GATE Developer** (GUI)?

Comment: Hi Many Thanks for your reply. Im a bit rusty with gate and wanted actually load a gazateer at run-time from within my application at run-time (the gaz is specificto the document). Ive started to get my gate mojo back and arbitrarily annotated a token, created and ran a default gazateer, and deleted the resource when complete.Whether this is effecient over 1000 documents or not I dont know!. Thanks