# Use database as gazetteers in Gate NLP

Tags: java, nlp, gate

Can we use database instead of  gazetteers  list in Gate NLP? If yes how can we do that? I am currently building Gate NLP program using Java. I couldn't find any document regarding using database instead of gazetteers.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30569624/1857897

Comment: If your database is a **RDF database** then use [Large KB Gazetteer](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch13.html#sec:gazetteers:lkb-gazetteer)

Comment: May be usefull: https://github.com/johann-petrak/gateplugin-JdbcLookup

Comment: @dedek Thank you very much. I think it will help :)